# "COPY" statement with "REPLACING" in COBOL

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I am getting compilation error as,

A "COPY" statement with "REPLACING" phrase was found within a nested "COPY".

This is our compilation setting that we can not use REPLACING verb in nested copy.
We have one copybook which is having multiple copy statements with replacing verb.
Can anyone help me  to resolve this error?

Comment: The error message says it all. Try to un-nest the copy. Show some of the code to get more help. (It's almost 30 years ago that I've worked with cobol, I never thought people are still using it :-)

Comment: We can un-nest the copybook..but for reusability of code we have created it in that way. I am just trying to search is there anny other way of doing that. My COBOL PGM contains: COPY ABC. and Copybook ABC has , COPY XYZ REPLACING ==:A:== BY ==B-==. COPY PQR REPLACING ==:A:== BY ==B-==. COPY LMN REPLACING ==:A:== BY ==B-==.

Comment: From http://www.mainframegurukul.com/tutorials/programming/cobol/cobol-copy.html: COPY statements can be nested. However, a) Nested COPY statements cannot contain the REPLACING phrase, and a COPY statement with the REPLACING phrase cannot contain nested COPY statement b) Nested COPY statement cannot cause recursion. But it is not advisbale to use nested COPY statements, as it will impacts readability of the program.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nesting COPYBOOKS in COBOL is a bit of a trick. In general
you may nest copybooks only if they do not
contain the `REPLACING` phrase and do not cause recursion.

Suppose you had the following two copybooks:

**COPYBOOK ABC**

```
  01 :A:-VAR-A1     PIC X.
  01 :A:-VAR-A2     PIC X.
  COPY XYZ REPLACING ==:A:== BY ==B==.
```

and

**COBPYOOK XYZ**

```
  01 :A:-VAR-X1     PIC X.
  01 :A:-VAR-X2     PIC X.
```

The nesting in COPYBOOK ABC is not allowed because it contains a `REPLACING` phrase.

However, you can do the following. Drop `RELACING` from COPYBOOK ABC so
it becomes:

**COPYBOOK ABC**

```
  01 :A:-VAR-A1     PIC X.
  01 :A:-VAR-A2     PIC X.
  COPY XYZ.
```

Now include COPYBOOK ABC into your source program as follows:

```
  REPLACE ==:A:== BY ==B==.
  COPY ABC.
  REPLACE OFF.
```

The `REPLACE` directive causes all occurances of `:A:` to
be replaced by `B` until a `REPLACE OFF` directive is encountered, and these
replacements occur after all `COPY` directives have been actioned. The net
result of the above statements would be:

```
  01 B-VAR-A1     PIC X.    <== from ABC
  01 B-VAR-A2     PIC X.    <== from ABC
  01 B-VAR-X1     PIC X.    <== Nested copy of XYZ from ABC
  01 B-VAR-X2     PIC X.    <== Nested copy of XYZ from ABC
```

This is the only 'legal' way of performing replacements to nested copybooks
in COBOL that I am aware of.

Comment: Thanks a lot Neal :) I tried above solution and it is working fine and resolved my problem. Thanks a lot for saving lot of efforts and redundant coding :)

Answer (score 1):

While Neal's answer may be correct for the Cobol variant he and the OP are using, it is worth noting that some Cobol compilers *will* allow nested `COPY ... REPLACING` statements.

Indeed we have many instances where we use this in our code.

For example, I have many Cobol module programs that include a copymember in the following way:

```
COPY 'uwxxxxsel.prg' REPLACING
             LEADING "xxxxSEL" BY "AREASEL".
```

and the 'uwxxxxsel.prg' copymember contains the following `COPY` of another file as follows:

```
COPY 'uwf8list.prg'
       REPLACING LEADING 'XXXXXX-F8-' BY 'SELECT-F8-'
                 ==FUNCTION-KEY== BY ==F8-FUNCTION-KEY==.
```

and this works fine.

I use this as a kind of 'inheritance' structure for common functionality.

There is one gotcha, though, with our Compiler. The higher level `REPLACING` does not continue after the nested `REPLACING`, but as long as the nested `REPLACING` is the last thing in the copymember, it is fine.